# Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a normal population with mean $\theta$ and variance $\theta^2$.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a normal population with mean $\theta$ and variance $\theta^2$.Find an unbiased estimator of $\theta^3$ based on both sample mean and sample variance.

I tried by getting $\bar X \sim N(\theta,\frac{\theta^2}{n})$.
Now, $E(X-\theta)^3=(\theta)^3+3 \theta^3 \implies \theta^3+E(3\bar X S^2)$ as $S, \bar X$ are independent.
Therefore , $E[(\bar X -\theta)^3-3 \bar X S^2]=\theta^3$
So, will it be an unbiased estimator?

Comment: That is not a statistic in the first place, being dependent on the unknown parameter. So the question of it being an estimator does not arise.

Comment: For a random sample, sample mean is an unbiased estimator of population mean and sample variance is an unbiased estimator of population variance. 

So, $$E_{\theta}(\bar{X}S^2)=E_{\theta}(\bar X)E_{\theta}(S^2)=\theta\times\theta^2$$ for all $\theta$, and you readily have your unbiased estimator.